# Upload image script is not working

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading, pathinfo

I have an image uploading script
In upload form page there is an input field as shown below:

Part of the php script handling image upload  is:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES['product_image']['name']);
$imgext = $path_parts['extension'] ;

$imgextension = "." . $imgext ; //

// copying files to server
$target = "targetdomainpath/products/";
$target = $target . $_POST['product_name'].$imgextension;

//copying image
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    //Tells you if its all ok
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and information has been modified inside the directory";
} else {
    //Gives and error if its not
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file. or you didnt select photo from the computer";
}
// end image copying
```

My problem is file is not uploading. Could you please help me

Comment: Please can you post the HTML for the form that you're submitting from.  Also are any of your error messages appearing?

Comment: You mean you get "Sorry, there was a problem" or just the file isn't there? Did you check folder exists and has the right permissions? Also, where does `$_FILES['uploadedfile']` come from? shoulnd' t  it be `$_FILES['product_image']` ?

Comment: As a bit of constructive criticism, please don't comment your code this way. Your comments aren't helpful, they simply state what each line already states in code. You should explain *why* something is doing what it does, not how it does it.

Comment: Sorry I missed input fields. 1) input type "file" name "product_image" 2) input type "text" name "product_name". The said Folder exists here and has right permission (777).

Comment: Have you put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your <form> tag?

Comment: Oh! I missed (enctype="multipart/form-data") in form tag. Thank you Coulton

Comment: @meagar, once I was working on some code where I found the following: `int v1; //this is a variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a [var_dump](http://us.php.net/var_dump) on `$_FILES` and if it's empty you're probably not submitting your form correctly.

Forms that include files must contain a `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Good luck!

Comment: Sometimes we forgot to check basic things. Thanks foryour Answer